# Would I benefit from switching to Lubuntu or Xubuntu?

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, xubuntu, lubuntu

I just settled down with my ideal setup, a dual boot of Windows 7 and Ubuntu, but for some reason Ubuntu's running slow for me. I heard that Ubuntu was pretty small and resource light, but should I switch to Lubuntu or Xubuntu? It means a lot because I have all of my shared files on my Linux partition so it would mean moving everything all over again.

Here are my specs from system monitor:

Ubuntu
Release 12.10 (quantal) 64-bi5
GNOME 3.6.0

Hardware
Memory: 2.9 GiB

Processor: Intel Core 2 Duo CPU T5850 @ 2.16GHz x2

Graphics:NVIDIA GeForce 8400M GS.

The computer itself is from 2008, I'm really trying to squeeze all I can out of it.

I'll be on this page for the next couple of hours so I'll respond to any replies. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You do not mention RAM? Also; onboard or dedicated graphics? I have GNOME Session Fallback on a C2D & it flies compared to 7 which chugs.

Comment: @fleamour - RAM's there - "memory: 2.9GiB"

Comment: My bad, or bad formatting...

Comment: @Fleamour: Added graphics info. I'm not really sure what you're talking about..."GNOME Session Fallback on a C2D"...is that another operating system or just a configuration of ubuntu?

Comment: @scott goodgame: that would be awesome, it would make my ubuntu faster? and turn it into lubuntu? if it's true that's great news.

Comment: Sorry. C2D; Core 2 Duo. GNOME Session Fallback is a basic DE (Desktop Environment) like other *buntu environments that can be installed instead of Unity.

Comment: ty fleamour. and my bad about the formatting. can switching the destkop environment happen inside the *buntu system or does it have to happen outside it?

Comment: Provided installed, the option of which/each DE is presented at login screen/prompt. You can only choose to boot one DE at a time from any one instance of Ubuntu.

Comment: Since you have less than 4 GB RAM, you might get a speed advantage if you just installed the 32-Bit version. Otherwise, your specs should make Ubuntu fly compared to Windows 7. Adding an SSD makes the real wonder.

Comment: I've tested with Gnome-session-fallback and it isn't so hot either, it's just a little bit slower than my Win 7 partition. Also before I even get to the login screen where I get to choose what flavor I want that also takes a while, for about 10 seconds or so I'm looking at a black screen. Why is this happening? Do i just need to spend money on ram?

Comment: Couple things...  Which video drivers are you using?  Also, is the entire system sluggish, or just a slower boot time?  If boot time is a concern I would search for tweaks, you can adjust timeouts and possibly some services from starting.

Answer (score 2):

You can always just install the Xubuntu/Lubuntu desktops from the command line without affecting your current situation.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to go to a terminal. Then,

For Xubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

And for Lubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

Now log out and log back in again. You'll be presented with choices to use for the present session.

Comment: I think you might not be presented with the choice after logging in, but that the choice is there on the login screen.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you are certain you want to leave plain Ubuntu, and depending on how much hard drive space you have, you could re-partition the Ubuntu installation using `gparted` into two sections.  Use one for each of Lubuntu and Xubuntu.  Keep the existing `/swap` partition as it is.  Each partition needs about 5GB minimum, but would be better with 20GB each.  Then you can triple boot and give a lengthy test to each version, to see which you end up comfortable with.